# What exact format is expected the latitudeInMicroDegrees and longitudeInMicroDegrees when creating a geoPoint for a Proximity CampaignCriterion?

Tags: ruby, google-ads-api

For example, when I have a latitude in decimal degrees of 45.3911638 and I convert it to microdegrees as 45391163, I am seeing the following error:

> [CriterionError.INVALID_LATITUDE @
>   operations[0].operand.criterion.geoPoint.latitudeInMicroDegrees]

Here's my code:

```
    {
      :operator => 'ADD',
      :operand => {
        :campaign_id => self[:campaign_id],
        :criterion => {
          :xsi_type => 'Proximity',
          :geo_point => {
            :latitude_in_micro_degrees => (shop[:lat] * 1_000_000).to_i,
            :longitude_in_micro_degrees => (shop[:lng] * 1_000_000).to_i
          },
          :radius_distance_units => RADIUS_DISTANCE_UNITS,
          :radius_in_units => radius
        }
      }
    }
```

> **UPDATE:** I was getting the error because I was submitting the `latitude_in_micro_degrees` twice; once with the `lat` value and a
>   second time with the `lng` value. The original question, which was
>   "What exact format is expected the latitudeInMicroDegrees and
>   longitudeInMicroDegrees when creating a geoPoint for a Proximity
>   CampaignCriterion?" still stands and is not documented AFAIK, but the
>   code (as presented above) actually does work, and I can now answer my
>   own question.

Comment: Obviously, I've checked the docs here https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201603/CampaignCriterionService.GeoPoint, and it merely specifies the field as an integer that cannot be null. I'm sure there's a valid range and format, but it's not specified.

Answer (score 3):

Google's documentation merely states:

> **xsd:int**
>
> Micro degrees for the latitude.
>
> This field is required and should not be **null**.

But, as it turns out, one microdegree is one millionth of one degree. So, assuming your latitude and longitude values are in decimal degrees (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees), you multiply by 1,000,000 and round to the nearest integer value. It's important to have 7 decimal places of precision so you can round to 6.